# SVG slight jump effect in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, effect

i need to use javascript to make a slight jumping effect on an svg, at the same time as i have a function making my square change colors when hovering it. but i dont know where to put the function that slightly alters the position of the square upwards. 
what i want is for my black square to turn white and go slightly upwards while hovering, and then black back down when the mouse isn't over it anymore.

the function for hovering and changing colors is this

```
function hoverColor(evt) {
    var target = evt.target;
    target.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'white');

function unHoverColor(evt) {
    var target = evt.target;
    target.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', 'black');
```

these are then put into an `addEventListener('mouseover', hovercolor, false)`

i want to put something like

```
target.setAttributeNS('transform', 'translate(0, 10');
```

at the bottom of that code but im not sure this is the correct thing to use/syntax.

I'm very new to javascript and haven't coded much before hope this was understandable !

Comment: Hey, Biotikc! I think you'll get better answers to this question if you focus on one part of the problem you're having trouble with. But to break the problem down a bit--use a CSS class definition for each of the two states and get that so applying either class to the element shows it as you intend. And then write event-handling code to apply one of the two classes in response to events. I think you're on the right path here--be specific about which part gives you trouble, and write a question focused on that part.

Comment: Yes, you need to add a null to that line too, but it looks right. Side note: I know you said you have to use javascript, but this could be done automatically using css :hover too.

Comment: thank you for the answer, unfortunately this project only allows javascript. i have however found that i can animate the SVG itself! in the HTML, after the SVG i can write in <animation and make some minor tweaks to the movement there. nevertheless, thank you